# Appending to numpy array column wise

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array

```
a = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 3, 4]
    ])
```

and 3 more column wise arrays

```
b=np.array([[1],
[2],
[3]])

c=np.array([[5],
[6],
[7]])

d=np.array([[9],
[10],
[11]])
```

I want to concatenate my array such the column wise arrays are appended to the original array "a" like this

```
a = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 3, 4],
    [1, 5, 9],
    [2, 6, 10],
    [3, 7, 11],
    ])
```

Comment: `np.concatenate([a,b.T,c.T,d.T])`?

Comment: it didn't work, I think I didn't word the question correctly. PLease have a look again at the question

Comment: You won't get a useful answer if your dummy example does not match the real case in a meaningful way.  The dummy `a` is (2,3) shape, not (n,).

Answer (score 0):

```
def st():
    a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[2, 3, 4]])
    b=np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
    c=np.array([[5],[6],[7]])
    d=np.array([[9],[10],[11]]) 

    return np.vstack([a, np.hstack([b,c,d])])
```

Results:

```
>>> st()
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 2,  3,  4],
       [ 1,  5,  9],
       [ 2,  6, 10],
       [ 3,  7, 11]])
```

Comment: @NeelShukla you’re welcome. An accepted answer and an up arrow would be appreciated. ;)